# Grails App fails to deploy to Heroku?

Tags: grails, plugins, heroku

I have developed a Grails application and have deployed it many times to Heroku without an issue. However just recently I have changed the solution to use plugins from within a folder I have called "plugins". I have then basically added the following code to the BuildConfig in order to include those plugins in the application:

```
grails.plugin.location.'spring-security-ui'="plugins/grails-spring-security-ui"
```

Now when I run the delpoy to Heroku I get the following error:

```
|Generating plugin.xml for inline plugin
       Error |
       Error executing script War: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'file' on null object (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
 !     Failed to build app
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Grails app
```

I think this is due to the new plugins I have added to the solution via the new method. Can anyone tell me if I am missing something or what is wrong??

Also I have tested this locally and runs fine :-S

Thanks

EDIT 1......

I have tried to build the WAR file locally i got the following:

```
Building WAR file.....
| Error Exception occurred trigger event [CreateWarStart]: /home/admin/workspace/APP_NAME/grails-app/migrations does not exist. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Done creating WAR target/APP_NAME-0.1.war
```

Comment: What happens if you run `grails war` locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From trying multiple different things I have found that Heroku is rubbish at handling local plugins within Grails. So I moved over to [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/) and runs like a dream :-)

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try `grails war` locally to see if you can reproduce the problem.

This might possibly be related to [GRAILS-9006](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9006) which was fixed in 2.0.4.

Comment: I have updated the post above with the suggested method results, any ideas?

Comment: Has anyone got idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: are you running the DB migrations plugin?

Comment: I have checked the applications.properties and that plugin is not listed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is there anyone else who has had this issue or can help as this is mind boggling :-S

Comment: It might also be in `BuildConfig.groovy`